# Selection from List of tuple to List of objects C#

Tags: c#, linq, type-conversion, tuples

In my C# code I have a list `List<Tuple<int,string>>`. I want to select/convert this to a `List<Type>`. I want to avoid iterating my list of tuple and insert in other list. Is there any way to do this? Maybe with LINQ?

Comment: LINQ also iterates, it just doesn't show in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change type of list. You only can create new list of another type and fill it with converted values from your list. I suggest to use [`List<T>.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which exists exactly for this purpose:

```
List<Tuple<int, string>> tuples = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
// ...
List<YourType> types =
     tuples.ConvertAll(t => new YourType { Foo = t.Item1, Bar = t.Item2 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown this type, but i assume that it contains an `int`- and a `string`-property:

```
List<MyType> result = tupleList
    .Select(t => new MyType { IntProperty = t.Item1, StringProperty = t.Item2 })
    .ToList();
```

another option: [`List.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
List<MyType> result = tupleList.ConvertAll(t => new MyType { IntProperty = t.Item1, StringProperty = t.Item2 });
```

This presumes that your `List<Type>` is actually a `List<CustomType>` (I've called it `MyType`).

> I want to avoid iterating my list of tuple and insert in other list.

LINQ does not avoid loops, it hides them just.